# Which certificate gives more skills LPIC or RHCSA and which distro to choose CentOS or RedHat?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, certificates

Can you give me some advise on which cert should I focus? LPIC or RHCSA? I want to do one of the certifications to learn some more skills and prove that I know the things at some level.

From what I have read is that RHCSA is a practical exam where LPIC is a multiple choice exam. By looking at it it looks like RHCSA will be a a lot more challanging to do get it but I guess you will learn more from it. What are your opinions?

My Other question will be. Is it OK to use CentOS to prepare for the RHCSA or it is better to use RedHat OS itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did **RHCSA** exam .

Yes it is challenging exam.

You need to have below mentioned abilities to pass the **RHCSA** exam.

1.Good Lab practice.

2.Better Understand a concepts in **Redhat linux**.

I think better to do **RHCSA**.

Comment: That's what I am thinking. I will have option to pay for my learning resources by the company so i am actually thinking to get online training directly from RedHat. Do you have any experience with their learning material? It is costly but if it is one of the best on the market then why not.

Comment: I purchase Redhat books for RHCSA Exam.Then after understand concepts while I am practice labs in Books.I think it is a best way to pass the exam.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the reply. Did you purchase official RHCSA books?

Comment: I went to RHCSA class. So they provide me offical RHCSA books.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will definitely get an official RHCSA and also probably some online material.

Answer (score 1):

I'm both LPIC and RHCSA certified.  As you said, LPIC is a multiple questions exam and is more theoretical, while RHCSA is a hands-on exam and requires you to have the practical knowledge to operate as a sysadmin on a RHEL machine.

Both certifications are interesting to take but, if you want to prove your technical skills, I'd recommend the RHCSA. Moreover, Linux in corporate environment is mostly RHEL/CentOS, which is the subject of RHCSA (while LPIC focuses on multiple Linux distros).

Comment: That's what I am thinking is well. It is actually goof to have them both but RHCSA is considered as prove of practical skills which is really important. You can have all the theory from the LPIC but if you have a lack of practical skills you can break more than fix it... But this is only my personal opinion about it.

Comment: Would you also recommend RedHat Online Training? Also would it be ok to use CentOS for the preparation for the exam or you would recommend evaluation version of the RedHat?